# Differentiate row in listview according to sqlite result

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, load, populate

In my project I need to get the messages from webservice and view that in listview.I need to differentiate the read and unread messages in listview.I retrieved message and I stored it in sqlite database.How can I differentiate read and unread messages.And also the listview does not populate properly.Instead of showing the text it shows textview ids in some row.

Here is my code,

```
      public class Message_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message> implements OnClickListener {
        Activity activity;
        int layoutResourceId;
        Message user;
        ArrayList<Message> data = new ArrayList<Message>();

        public Message_Adapter(Activity act, int layoutResourceId,
            List<Message> data) {
            super(act, layoutResourceId, data);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.activity = act;
            this.data = (ArrayList<Message>) data;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            UserHolder holder = null;

            if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);

            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new UserHolder();
            holder.fromnum = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.fromno);
            holder.tonum = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tonum);
            holder.body= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.msgbody);
            holder.date = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.msgdate);
            holder.delete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
            holder.status = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.staty);
            row.setTag(holder);
            } else {
            holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
            }
            user = data.get(position);
            smsm=user.getID();
            System.out.println("Smsm::::"+smsm);
            holder.delete.setTag(user.getID());
            holder.fromnum.setText(user.getmsgfrom());
            holder.tonum.setText(user.getto());
            holder.body.setText(user.getmsg());
            holder.date.setText(user.getdate());
            holder.status.setText(user.getstatus());


            holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // show a message while loader is loading

                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
                adb.setTitle("Delete?");
                adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete ");
                //final int user_id = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
                adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                adb.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which) {
                        // MyDataObject.remove(positionToRemove);
                        DatabaseHandler dBHandler = new DatabaseHandler(
                            activity.getApplicationContext());
                        dBHandler.Delete_Contact(smsm);
                       InboxActivity.this.onResume();

                    }
                    });
                adb.show();
            }

            });
            row.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));

            return row;

        }
```

This is my inbox custom layout,

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100sp"
android:background="@drawable/edittext"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fromno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tonum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msgbody"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msgdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/staty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: which variable from the database do you use to differentiate between read and unread messages?

can you put up a picture of what you see with the wrong population?

Comment: I have the column named Status.For that rows which has 0 value have to different from rows that has 1 value...

Comment: @Lena Bru, I cant able upload screenshots...Instead of loading textview details it loads the resource ids of those textviews text

Comment: post the xml of layoutResourceId to which you inflate your row for me to see what may be the reason for the resource ids

Comment: @Lena bru!!I have pasted my custom row layout

Comment: holder.fromnum.setText(user.getmsgfrom());
            holder.tonum.setText(user.getto());
are user.getmsgfrom() and user.getmsgto numbers or strings?

Comment: @Lenu Bru all are strings

Comment: which fields are the problematic ones?

Comment: all fields are problematic only

Comment: show me your getCount() method

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            UserHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity); <== move this line to the constructor of the adapter,and use it as a member

        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new UserHolder();
        holder.fromnum = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.fromno);
        holder.tonum = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tonum);
        holder.body= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.msgbody);
        holder.date = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.msgdate);
        holder.delete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
        holder.status = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.staty);
        row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
        holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        user = data.get(position);
        smsm=user.getID();
        System.out.println("Smsm::::"+smsm);
        holder.delete.setTag(user.getID());
        holder.fromnum.setText(user.getmsgfrom());
        holder.tonum.setText(user.getto());
        holder.body.setText(user.getmsg());
        holder.date.setText(user.getdate());
        holder.status.setText(user.getstatus());


        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // show a message while loader is loading

            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            adb.setTitle("Delete?");
            adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete ");
            //final int user_id = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
            adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int which) {
                    // MyDataObject.remove(positionToRemove);
                    DatabaseHandler dBHandler = new DatabaseHandler(
                        activity.getApplicationContext());
                    dBHandler.Delete_Contact(smsm);
                   InboxActivity.this.onResume();

                }
                });
            adb.show();
        }

        });
        row.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));// do not put onItemClickListener here, it is supposed to go into the activity or fragment whereever your listview object resides, give it "listView.setOnItemClickListener()", it will be noticable in performance when your listview has a lot of rows, that their click listeners get restarted every time you scroll or refresh the list



            if(Status == 0){
    //message is unread
    }else {
      // message is read
} // this status will change whenever you call notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter, because it will refresh all the rows in view


        return row;

    }
```